# Multiplicative group modulo prime number $p$: find generator for number $a$

Tags: group-theory, number-theory, finite-groups

Consider subgroup $S$ generated by number $a$ in multiplicative group modulo prime number $p$:
$$
S_1=\left( 1, a\bmod p, a^2\bmod p, a^3\bmod p,\ldots\right)
$$
Is there a quick way to find its generator? I mean the smallest $b$, and its subgroup $S_2$ generated in the same way:
$$
S_2=\left( 1, b\bmod p, b^2\bmod p, b^3\bmod p, \ldots \right)
$$
such as $S_1=S_2$.

Comment: The group should be $1,a,a^2,\dots$

Comment: @lhf thanks, you are right

Comment: The smallest in what sense ? $a$ is fine, why do you care of the "size" of your generator ?

Comment: @reuns my problem is more complex, I am trying to understand what is the best approach to solve by splitting into smaller problems. I wanted to compare 2 subgroups with different generators $a$ and $b$ by comparing their smallest possible generator. If this is hard to do, then I need to find another approach.

Comment: Because it is cyclic, two subgroups of $\Bbb{F}_p^\times$ are equal iff they have the same number of elements, ie. $order(a\bmod p)= order(b\bmod p)$.

Comment: Theorem (Fermat): $S$ is a cyclic group with $p-1$ members..  Tf $g$ is a generator for $S$ and $a\equiv g^n \mod p$ with $1\le n\le p-1$ then let $m=\gcd(p-1,n).$ Then  $S_1$ has $(p-1)/m=r$ members.  The generators for $S_1$ are all $g^{mc}$ for $c\ge 1$ and $\gcd(c,r)=1$.... I dk whether there is an efficient way to find $g$ or $n$ or to find $b.$

Comment: There is no general way of finding the smallest primitive root; there isn’t even a general fast way of finding *a* primitive root. There are some bounds known for the smallest primitive root in terms of $p$. [The Wikipedia page on primite roots](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primitive_root_modulo_n?wprov=sfti1) has some information.

Comment: thanks, you gave me some good ideas